# How to View Comments in the Method Navigator of Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Does anyone know how to view comments in the method navigator in Xcode 4

In Xcode 3 these would put comments like:

```
???: Huh?
!!!: Woah
MARK: Aliens
TODO: Fix this
```

in here...

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 3, those kinds of comments and their display in the menu were defined in the file /Developer/Library/Private Frameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Resources/BaseSupport.xclangspec (that's Xcode Language Specification). I don't know what the equivalent is in Xcode 4, which is why I'm not posting an answer, but I thought that tidbit may be useful to you in hunting this down; maybe you can figure out what the xclangspec equivalent is in v4.

Comment: I checked the apple developer forum. A bug report has been filed. Here's the response from Apple: 
 
"This is a follow up to Bug ID# 9159086.  After further investigation it  has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being  investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug  database under the original Bug ID# 7604687"

Comment: Same problem here. I just could't find where to view those comments.

Comment: To be clear, these kinds of comments *will* appear in the function popup if they are outside any function/method body; inside functions/methods, they appear in Xcode 3 but not in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use // ???:, // FIXME: and // TODO: comments *outside* of methods to get the comment to pop up in the method navigator.

I know that some people would like these type of comments within methods to  still show up in the method navigator and that there is a bug report filed against this, but I actually like this bug, as it forces me to keep my methods clean.  I find that putting the // TODO:, etc., above the method creates better code readability.

Just my opinion.

Comment: I disagree - Apple please fix this bug!

Answer (score 0):

You can even to that in one line (comment and separator):

so instead of:

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark MyCoolMethod
```

Just type as below:

```
#pragma mark - MyCoolMethod
- (void) myCoolMethod {
    //Code here...
}
```

Comment: I know about pragma's but that's not what I am asking about.

Comment: Dude you don't understand what @MakingScienceFictionFact was talking about here.

Answer (score -2):

use the following:

```
#pragma mark your_comment_here
```

You can also use the following to add separator lines:

```
#pragma mark -
```

Comment: you don't understand the problem.