# Comment tags no longer appear in Xcode nav/jump bar

Tags: xcode4, comments, pragma

In Xcode3, comment tags like `// !!!:` or `// TODO:` would show up as #pragma markers in the navigation bar for the source file. In Xcode4, none of them show up anymore.

Perhaps this is because the BaseSupport.xclangspec, in which they are defined, is now at a different address? Since I changed the name of the developer folder for Xcode4, it now resides here: `/DeveloperXcode4_02/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/BaseSupport.xclangspec`.

I doubt that is really the problem, though, because I see that that file defines other comment handling, like `/* */` block-style comments, and those still work.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Edit: It turns out such comments do show up in the nav bar, but only when they are *outside* of a method. Which is nonsensical -- when would you ever put a comment there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to View Comments in the Method Navigator of Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616748/how-to-view-comments-in-the-method-navigator-of-xcode-4)